# VM loses copy/paste and folder sharing after host crash

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I am using a virtualbox Version 5.2.14 r123301 (Qt5.6.2) on a Windows 7 EE SP1 host.

I have run so far and with no problem an Ubuntu 16.4 VM, with the help of Guest Additions. Copy/paste from/to host was possible, as well as folder sharing.

But yesterday, my host suddenly crashed and I had to restart it : the VM was thus not closed the proper way.
And I realized as a consequence that I cannot copy/paste anymore, or see whatever is on my host from a previously shared folder (it appears on the fs, but is empty!).

I have tried to reinstall back the guest additions from command line (apt-get install VBox-Guest-Additions.iso), and run them : but I ended up loosing my full screen (now ubuntu is just a small window in the middle of my virtual box main window)... I got the folder sharing back, though, but this would be nearly acceptable if I had not lost the Guest Additions CD mounting in the meantime.

It already arrived once, and I ended up recovering and old working image (loosing a lot of recent data in the operation, even though all critical ones were on a remote repo)

Any tip, idea on what I can do to restore this without building a new VM or loosing a lot of data??

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the right way (didn't expect to fix it that fast this time!), combining two solutions

I followed those steps :

1. https://askubuntu.com/a/850131/834808 => step 4 & 5
2. apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
3. reboot
4. from the VM host menu, "devices" >  "insert Guest addition ISO CD"... and let it autorun

Everything is now back : copy/paste, full screen, folder sharing, and my mood!